# Finding the value of distribution function of a converging random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

There is this example in a note that I think this is supposed to be a simple problem, but I still find it not as straightforward.

Consider a sequence of random variables $X_n\equiv1/n,X\equiv0$. Then $F_{X_n}(t)\to F_X(t)$ at all $t\not=0$ (as $n\to\infty$), but how can we show that $F_X(0)=1$ and $F_{X_n}(0)=0$? (in other words, how can we compute $F_X(t)$ and $F_{X_n}(t)$ at $t=0$?)
(these values are given, I just don't know how they come up with these).

I tried to reason as follows:
1. Since $X$ and $X_n$ are constant random variables, then both $F_X(0)$ and $F_{X_n}(0)$ should equal to $0$, am I right? or at least they should equal in value?
2. It was not said explicitly, but I suppose $t\in \mathbb{R}$. My question is does it affect $F_{X_n}(t)$ and $F_X(t)$ afterall?

The purpose of this example is I think to illustrate convergence in distribution only applies at $t\in \mathbb{R}$ where $F_X(t)$ is continuous.

I am so confused about this problem for so long. I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you defining $F_X(t)$?  It seems to be different from the standard definition.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: @Tim. I think the $F_X(t)$ has the same meaning as the standard one. What makes you think it is different?

Comment: My mistake, I'm stupid on Sundays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by $X_n \equiv \frac{1}{n}$ you mean that $X_n$ *always* takes the value $\frac{1}{n}$. $X_n$ then corresponds to a probability measure $\mathbb{P}_n$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ iff $\frac{1}{n} \in A$. $X$ similarly corresponds to a probability measure with $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ iff $0 \in A$.

The distribution function $F_n$ of $X_n$ is thus $$
  F_n(t) = \begin{cases}
    0 &\text{if $t < \frac{1}{n}$} \\
    1 &\text{if $t \geq \frac{1}{n}$.}
  \end{cases}
$$
and the distribution function $F$ of $X$ is $$
  F(t) = \begin{cases}
    0 &\text{if $t < 0$} \\
    1 &\text{if $t \geq 0$.}
  \end{cases}
$$

Now, if you pick a $t > 0$, then for all $n > \frac{1}{t}$ you get $F_n(t) = 1$. Thus, for all $t > 0$, you have $F_n(t) \to 1 = F(t)$. For $t < 0$, you have for all $n$ that $F_n(t) = 0 = F(t)$. In other words, $F_n \to F$ *pointwise* on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

For $t=0$, $F_n(t) = F_n(0) = 0 \neq 1 = F(0)$ for *all* $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Does that mean that the $X_n$ do not converge in distribution? No, because $F_n$ only needs to converge pointwise to $F$ for those points $x$ where $F$ is continuous. And $F$ isn't continuous at $0$.

So, why *is* convergence in distribution defined this way? One way to look at this is to ask whether requiring the $F_n$ to converge only at continuity points of $F$ somehow makes the limit ambiguous. It turns out it does not, because one you know the value of $F$ at those points, you can recover the *full* $F$ by using that since $F$ is a distribution function, it's always  right-continuous, i.e., $\lim_{x\to a^+} F(x) = F(a)$. (I've cheated a bit here, because two different $F$ may have two *different* sets of continuity points, but this still explains the general idea..)

Take your example. You know that $F_n$ goes to $1$ for $t > 0$, and to $0$ for $t < 0$. There then is only *one* right-continuous $F$ which *fits*, since the right-continuity at $0$ requires that $F(0)=1$ too. So the $F_n$ uniquely defined $F$, even though there's a point where the pointwise convergence fails.

Comment: @Did Done, but (a) the risk of confusion was low I think and (b) your comment is a bit more commanding than I feel is warranted here...

Comment: Thanks fgp. Just to mention, maybe you have mistakenly written in your definition of F(t) $t\ge1$, which I think it should be $t\ge0$? But overall, I got it, thanks!

Comment: @user71346 Yup, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out!